# Run PyQGIS script always - in the background

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

How to always run a PyQGIS, in the background?

In my case, I want to delete "feature A", the polygon, that have a "attribute X", if feature B, the lines, that have "attribute X" as well.

[image]

Comment: Search for Qt multi-threading and especially for `QThreadPool`. Or if it's just a script without GUI interface, go for pure python multi-threading with `_thread` or `threading`.

Comment: Something like this should be possible using a python script but how will the data be stored, shapefile, dataebase, etc?  Will multiple users be involved?  I am not sure about the "always in the background" part though.  Why do you need it always running?

Comment: @GreyHippo Thanks, as well as for J.Monticolo
...how will the data be stored, shapefile, dataebase, etc? The feature that the user delete, and the feature that qgis may delete, are PostGIS layer type. 
Will multiple users be involved? Yes, 10 users using a PostGIS DB
Why do you need it always running? Because, the feature I delete is a polygon, and the feature qgis may delete is a line layer that has the side dimension of the polygon, so I can automate the production, as the user don't have to delete the line layer himself. I edited my question, and added a picture of it.

Comment: Two ideas to start with: build a trigger on the Postgis side, that fires when the polygon gets deleted. Or connect a script to the signal featureDeleted of the QgsVectorLayer. As this signal informs about the fid of the deleted feature, you need some logic to join this to the line layer